# How to get search query from the hash in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

I am adding a Search feature, and if the user is on the search results and they refresh the page I want it to stay at that search. I already put the search query into the URL, but I don't know how to retrieve it. It will most likely require a regexp so anyone that is experienced with regexp, please help.

[image: screenshot w/ description]

Here is how I put it into the URL:

```
function trimspace(str) {
    str = str.replace(/ +(?= )/g, '');
    return str;
}
function searchMail() {
    var query = trimspace($('#search_input').val());
    if (query == '' || !query || query == null) {
        $('#search_input').focus();
    }
    else {
        window.location.hash = '#!/search/' + query;
        $('#loader').show();
        $.get('tools.php?type=search', { q: query }, function(data, textStatus) {
            $('#loader').hide();
            if (textStatus == 'success') {
                hideAllTabs();
                $('#search_results').html(data).show();
                document.title = "Search results - WeeBuild Mail";
            }
            else {
                alertBox('Search failed. Please try again in a few minutes.', 2500);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And besides just retreiving the query I need to be able to detect if the hash is `#!/search/query`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detect if query is `#!/search/query`:

```
location.hash==='#!/search/query'
```

Finding out about the query parts assuming the query is `#!/search/query`:

```
var parts = location.hash.split('/');
```

`parts[0]` is `#!`. `parts[1]` is `search` and `parts[2]` is `test`. Doing with the parts want you want should now be trivial enough.

In response to the comments:

```
function getPartAndRemainder(){
    var parts = location.hash.split('/');
    if(parts[0]!=='#!' || parts.length<2){
        // Value after # does not follow the expected pattern #!/part/any_parameters
        throw new Error('Cannot parse application part.');
    }
    return {
        // Contains the part of your application (word after first slash after #)
        part: parts[1],
        // Contains everything after second slash after # or the empty string
        remainder: location.hash.substring(
            // Length of #! (or whatever somebody might use instead)
            parts[0].length
            // Length of first slash
            +1
            // Length of your application part's name
            +parts[1].length
            // Length of the second slash
            +1)
    };
}
```

The function gives back an object that contains the part of your application at the key `part` and the `remainder` key will contain the rest. So, if your URI would be `something#!/search/test` the function would return `{part:'search', remainder:'test'}`.
In case the URI can't be parsed, you'll get an error and you should then use a sensible default instead.

You would use the method as follows whenever the hash changes or at some other event (point in time) where you are interested in the hash value:

```
try {
    var hashValue = getPartAndRemainder();
    if(hashValue.part==='search'){
        var query = hashValue.remainder;
        alert('You searched: '+query)
    }
    if(hashValue.part==='inbox'){
        alert('You are in inbox, now');
    }
} catch(e){
    // It was not possible to parse the value after the # from URI according to our expected pattern.
    alert('No idea what to do with: '+location.hash);
}
```

Comment: I meant that 'query' is the actual query typed in (sorry for the confusion). But those parts should work, I'm trying it right now.

Comment: To clear up the confusion about the wording: Don't care to much about the word `query`. Reading `location.hash` just gives the part of the URI starting with `#`.

Comment: Yeah, but what I have to do is get the query (not including #!/search/ part). The reason why I need to do the detecting is because I have other hashes for other parts of my web app like #!/inbox etc. The part thing will work for getting the query but first I need to detect wether or not to split it. Do you understand what I want now? Thanks for all of your help so far :)

Comment: Wow! That is an awesome function. So if I called that function would I be able to use `remainder` as a variable or what? I'll also use `part` to see which one is in the URL. Can these be used as variables or do they need to be used another way?

Comment: See the usage sample in the edited post. The function tries to make sense out of the part after `#` in the URI and returns the part of your application and the remaining part of the URI. You can place the values from the function result in variables (see `query` in usage sample) or access the return value as object directly (see `hashValue.part` in the usage sample).

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match anything after the search param, is this what you are looking for?

```
/#1/search/(.*)/
```

Comment: That looks like what I want but how would I use it, like this? `var q = location.hash.match(/#1/search/(.*)/)` - and if so, would that return, for example, `test` if that is what is in the URL?

Comment: Also this is the format of it: `#!/search/query` (it isn't a `1`, it's a `!`.) Would anything need to be changed in that regex for a `!`?

Comment: `/#1/search/(.*)/`is not a valid js regex literal. You need to escape those forward slashes!

Answer (score 0):

```
var match = /\/.*\/.*\/(.*)\//i.exec(location.hash)
//match contain the query
```